# Grails 5.2.5 - Where are the templates list.gsp, table.gsp, etc.?

Tags: templates, grails, field, scaffolding

At the moment I would like to have references to the files _list.gsp, _table.gsp and the other files that should be in the _fields directory. But at the time of generating the templates this directory is not populated and there is no documentation on this subject.

Could you enlighten me on this matter?